# How to make a resume Header (HTML)

Tags: html

I want to make a resume header just like this

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o16CM.png)

I have tried this HTML code with less CSS to achieve this task

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 align="center">
        <img src="http://gocartoonme.com/wp-content/uploads/cartoon-avatar.png" 
width="10%" height="10%" align="middle">Sam<br clear="all"> 
        </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

But I could not achieve that resume header.

The expected output would be a Resume header just like the image mentioned above

Comment: What are your knowledge about HTML? They can be three divs with the float property.

Comment: I can use div , but my instructor said, dont use divs even if you know already about them

Comment: Yeah but stackoverflow is not a service to post full code to questions. I don't know which are your knoweledge about this field, I think very basic. Some possible solutions are using three div or a table (3 column x 1 row) but I would not suggest it or using positions (absolute and relative). All depends what you already learned

Comment: You can use [`span`](http://jsfiddle.net/n3sgmaqd/).

Comment: images in `<h1>` tags are advised against - really bad for SEO

Comment: @Davide  , how to use divs to achieve that  should i use float ?

Comment: @treyBake what to use instead ?

Comment: @UsmanRafiq keep text to `<h1>` and wrap imgs in divs instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with CSS fairly easily, using properly structured HTML:

HTML:

```
<div id="bio-intro">
    <div id="img-container">
        <img src="" alt="treybake Frontend Developer" />
    </div>
    <div id="bio-info">
        <h1>TreyBake</h1>
        <h3>Frontend Developer</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="bio-contact">
        <p>
            e: someemail@domain.com <br/>
            t: 0112233445566<br/>
            w: domain.com
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bio-intro {
  background: lightgray;
  width: 100%
}

#img-container, #bio-info, #bio-contact {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%
}

#img-container {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 100%;
  max-width: 150px
}
```

We essentially break up each *column* into it's own container. We set these containers to a 1/3 of the parent width and set the display to `inline-flex` to make a row. Everything else is simple CSS to create a bordered image (no image, hence you see the ALT attribute value on the image - replace with an image and you'll see a much better result).

[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/zjk67uhL/)

Comment: Thanks , @treyBlake I have tried that but the image is showing very weirdly

Comment: @UsmanRafiq https://jsfiddle.net/62dcbLar/ -> fixed, just target img instead of img-container

Comment: Do you think that the solution that you provided is similar to expected output ?

Comment: @UsmanRafiq layout wise - yes. It's not a copy-paste solution, StackOverflow is not a coding service, I've merely answered how-to - you need to do the rest :)

Comment: Okay , Thanks for the help and advice :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend flex-box.

You can assign "display:flex" to a element within which all your children are container, i.e., all the elements you are trying to align based on your requirements.

From there, flex-box provides numerous other features which you can explore here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Flex-box not only easy to implement, but it is also responsive. This may not be too important in your specific case, but something additional benefit to keep in mind while styling elements.

```
<li class="flex-container">
    <ul class="flex-item">Your image</ul>
    <ul class="flex-item">Your Name/Title</ul>
    <ul class="flex-item">Your contact</ul>
</li>

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/snehansh/fm3etpsu/5/

Comment: what does this code - should add an explanation so OP understands the solution/problem and can develop their developing skills :p

Comment: @tryBake : Good suggestion, I added some description, hopefully it helps.